# how to return to main menu?

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a problem how to return to the main menu. After depositing in the bank, I want to show the main menu to the user again but I don't know whats the problem here. To pinpoint my exact problem.. After depositing in the bank, the main menu should appear again when I input "Y" and click "ok" button but it doesn't appear.

Here is my program.

Base class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount    
{

    public BankAccount(double b, String n) 
    {
       double balance = b; 
       String name = n;
    }

    public void deposit(double d)
    {
        balance += d;
    }

    public void withdraw(double w)
    {
        balance -= w;
    }

    public String nickname()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a new name: ");
        Scanner kbIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = kbIn.nextLine();
        return n;
    }

    double balance;
    String name;

}
```

Test class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {
    private static String name;
    private static double bal;
    private static double withdraw;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner kbInLine = new Scanner(System. in );
        Scanner kbIn = new Scanner(System. in );


        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name: ");

        String num;
        int pin;
        num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your pin number: ");
        pin = Integer.parseInt(num);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success\n" + "Name : " + name + "\n" + "Pin Number : " + pin);



        BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount(withdraw, name);


        String[] buttons = {
            "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Print Balance", "Exit"
        };
        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "What would you like to do?",
            "Confirmation",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        0,
        null,
        buttons,
        buttons[2]);


        if (rc == 0) {
            int deposit;
            String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$ ");
            deposit = Integer.parseInt(num);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have deposited $" + dep + " into the account of " + name);

            String proceeds = "y";
            while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            do {
                proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            System.exit(0);
        }


        if (rc == 1) {
            double withdraw;
            String with = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to withdraw?\n\t$");
            withdraw = Integer.parseInt(num);
            if (bal - withdraw > 0) {
                myAccount.withdraw(withdraw);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have withdrawn $" + withdraw + " from the account of " + name + ". The new balance is: " + myAccount.balance);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you have insufficient funds for this operation. Your existing balance is $" + myAccount.balance);
            }

            String proceeds = "y";
            while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            do {
                proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (rc == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance in the account of " + name + " with the pin number " + num + " is $" + bal);



            String proceeds = "y";
            while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            do {
                proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            System.exit(0);
        }


        if (rc == -1) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nThank you. Have a good day!");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please use consistent and correct indentation and code format.

Comment: the problem is how to return to main menu using do / while..

Comment: @AsakaGhurl please just look at my post. I get it work for you. please feel free to ask any question or improve my code

Comment: you have many posts sir.. which is which??

Comment: @AsakaGhurl ok i just update my former post. Now everything is correct and works fine.

Comment: Nice now you have enough reputations to vote my answer up. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reorganize your class so that it can be more clear. I also make some  little changes to increase the performance. However i ready to accept all suggestions or critics.

BankAccount class

```
public class BankAccount {

    private double balance;

    private String name;

    public BankAccount(double b, String n) {
        this.balance = b;
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void deposit(double d) {
        balance += d;
    }

    public void withdraw(double w) {
        balance -= w;
    }

    public String nickname() {
        System.out.print("Enter a new name: ");
        Scanner kbIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = kbIn.nextLine();
        return n;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Tester class

```
    import java.awt.HeadlessException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Tester {

        private static String name;

    private static double withdraw;

    private static int pin;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner kbInLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kbIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name: ");

        String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your pin number: ");
        pin = Integer.parseInt(num);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success\n" + "Name : " + name + "\n" + "Pin Number : " + pin);

        BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount(withdraw, name);

        int rc = getRC();
        processor(myAccount, rc);
    }

    private static int getRC() throws HeadlessException {
        String[] buttons = { "Deposit", "Withdraw", "Print Balance", "Exit" };
        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            null,
            "What would you like to do?",
            "Confirmation",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            0,
            null,
            buttons,
            buttons[2]);
        return rc;
    }

    private static void processor(BankAccount myAccount, int rc) throws HeadlessException, NumberFormatException {
        switch(rc) {
            case 0:
                processDeposit(myAccount, rc);
                break;
            case 1:
                processWithdraw(myAccount, rc);
                break;
            case 2:
                processBalance(myAccount, rc);
            default:
                processExit(rc);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void processExit(int rc) throws HeadlessException {
        if(rc == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nThank you. Have a good day!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static void processDeposit(BankAccount myAccount, int rc) throws HeadlessException, NumberFormatException {
        double deposit;
        String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$ ");
        deposit = Double.parseDouble(dep);
        myAccount.deposit(deposit);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have deposited $" + dep + " into the account of " + name);
        processManager(myAccount);
    }

    private static void processWithdraw(BankAccount myAccount, int rc) throws HeadlessException, NumberFormatException {
        double withdraw;
        String with = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to withdraw?\n\t$");
        withdraw = Double.parseDouble(with);
        if(myAccount.getBalance() - withdraw >= 0) {
            myAccount.withdraw(withdraw);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have withdrawn $" + withdraw + " from the account of " + name
                    + ". The new balance is: " + myAccount.getBalance());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                "Sorry, you have insufficient funds for this operation. Your existing balance is $"
                        + myAccount.getBalance());
        }
        processManager(myAccount);
    }

    private static void processBalance(BankAccount myAccount, int rc) throws HeadlessException {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The balance in the account of " + name + " with the pin number " + pin
                + " is $" + myAccount.getBalance());
        processManager(myAccount);
    }

    private static void processManager(BankAccount myAccount) throws HeadlessException, NumberFormatException {
        int rc;
        String proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
        if(proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            rc = getRC();
            processor(myAccount, rc);
        } else {
            processExit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Your mistake was that, your structure was not good and you don't need do while absolutely in the withdraw method.

In my post: in `processWithdraw()` method i call the `getRc()` method which represents the main menu and return the value of the selected button. at end i passe the returned value to the `processor()`

Comment: thnx...
but my problem still not solved.

Comment: what I need is how to return to main menu after Depositing

Comment: what did you call here main menu? for me the main menu is where you have the 4 buttons. this is what i put in the getRc() method. you have to extract it in a method so that you can call it wherever you need it. if you've run my class as posted then they will work because i try them and it works. please open a new project and just make copy&paste run the main class and you'll see. after that you remove/add whatever you want

Comment: I figured it out and now its working but the problem now is :
for example.. I deposit 100 and tried to withdraw 90.. I got error :(

Comment: ok. this is a good beginning. i just optimize the code for withdraw. as you can see i didn't change nothing on processDeposite()  and others.

Comment: @Asaka Ghurl your main question to us was about how to return to the main menu. That is what i done.  however i can dig later it to solv the issue about the deposite. I'll let you know

Comment: sorry about that.. Im trying to figure it out though,, thank you very much sir.

Comment: @AsakaGhurl ok i just update my former post. Now everything is correct and works fine.

Comment: Im so sorry but my reputation is tooooo low :(
btw thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and look carefully. Why do you use **two** loops for proceede checking?

I think this is better:

```
if (rc == 0) {
        do {
            int deposit;
            String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$ ");
            deposit = Integer.parseInt(num);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have deposited $" + dep + " into the account of " + name);


             String proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            System.exit(0);
}
```

I said you are using **two loops** because your code:

```
while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            do {
                proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Just means

```
while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            do {
                proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another transaction? (Y/N)");
            } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

Which are **two different nested loops**.

Comment: still error on the "while" part.

Comment: I cant go back to main menu again after depositing.. why?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this few lines ?

```
 while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        do {
            proceeds = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\nWould you like to do another  transaction? (Y/N)");
        } while (proceeds.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Also, I'm not sure I understand why you think it should display the start menu, where all of you blocks end with `System.exit(0)` ... is this all your code ?

Comment: I want to return to main menu using that but I cant well, I really don't know how :(

Comment: What do you call the "main menu" in this case ? System.exit(0) will simply shut down your application. Is this what you want ? Do you actually *reach* the System.exit(0) line, or are you stuck in the "proceeds" loops (which you should probably fix, as explained by Desolator ?)

Comment: What do you mean by "error on the 'while part'" ? I'm sorry but I'm not sure I get what is happening, sorry ... If you replace the double loop with a single loop, what happens ? Does the dialog keep opening ? Does you application exits ?

Comment: I need to go back to main menu again after depositing some, but it doesn't show up...